# Go urlfetch.Transport.RoundTrip, can call in GET, but not POST?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, post, get, go

I'm having a problem getting any response from urlfetch.Transport.RoundTrip in GAE Go. When I browse a page that makes the call in a browser, the call is executed as intended. When the same function is called from a POST request made by [poclbm Bitcoin miner](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poclbm), I can't get a response.

The call is made by [this package I made](https://github.com/ThePiachu/Go-HTTP-JSON-RPC/blob/master/gaehttpjsonrpc/gaehttpjsonrpcClient.go) at line 77.

Is it possible, that in Google App Engine one can request data from other web pages under a HTTP GET, but not POST, or is there something else that can be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do POST request from App Engine using [http.Client.Post](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Post), just make sure you create  the http client with [urlfetch.Client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/reference#Client) function.